# Resizing a C++ std::vector<char> without initializing data

Tags: c++, stl, vector, resize

With vectors, one can assume that elements are stored contiguously in memory, allowing the range *[&vec[0], &vec[vec.capacity())* to be used as a normal array. E.g.,

```
vector<char> buf;
buf.reserve(N);
int M = read(fd, &buf[0], N);
```

But now the vector doesn't know that it contains *M* bytes of data, added externally by *read()*. I know that *vector::resize()* sets the size, but it also clears the data, so it can't be used to update the size after the *read()* call.

Is there a trivial way to read data *directly* into vectors and update the size after? Yes, I know of the obvious workarounds like using a small array as a temporary read buffer, and using *vector::insert()* to append that to the end of the vector:

```
char tmp[N];
int M = read(fd, tmp, N);
buf.insert(buf.end(), tmp, tmp + M)
```

This works (and it's what I'm doing today), but it just bothers me that there is an extra copy operation there that would not be required if I could put the data *directly* into the vector.

So, is there a simple way to modify the vector size when data has been added externally?

Comment: Are you sure `&buf[0]` works in debug mode? For instance, on Visual Studio, in debug mode `std::vector::operator[]` performs a range check. So that expression will throw if `buf` is empty.

Comment: I use GCC, and I ran the program through valgrind to make sure that no memory errors occured. All I can say is that with the GNU libstdc++ implementation, this works. &vec[0] seems to give you a direct pointer to reserved memory, no matter the size().

Comment: @user984228: if you're happy to rely on implementation details of GCC (which is a BAD IDEA (TM)), then you'd look at the source for its implementation of `vector`. You can see where it stores the `begin` and `end` pointers and capacity, and if you just overwrite the `end` pointer, I'm pretty sure that will change the size as you want. Just copy whatever the implementation of `resize()` does in the case where the capacity is big enough to start with, leaving out the memset/fill/whatever. You'll have to work around some `private` modifiers, of course, perhaps by hard-coding in the offsets.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I just died a little.

Comment: @Matthieu: quite. If all that stuff sounds like a bad idea, then hopefully relying on the fact that GCC appears to let you write into space that's only reserved, not resized, also sounds like a bad idea :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: of course it does, but then I have been tainted by interoperability at a young (programmer) age since I began with Windows/Linux programs (and they are QUITE different environments :p)

Comment: @Praetorian The [C++ standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) says _"No bounds checking is performed."_. So Visual Studio is obviously not obeying the standard.

Answer (score 28):

```
vector<char> buf;
buf.reserve(N);
int M = read(fd, &buf[0], N);
```

This code fragment invokes undefined behavior. You can't write beyond than `size()` elements, *even if you have reserved the space*.

The correct code is like:

```
vector<char> buf;
buf.resize(N);
int M = read(fd, &buf[0], N);
buf.resize(M);
```

---

*PS.* Your statement "With vectors, one can assume that elements are stored contiguously in memory, allowing the range *`[&vec[0], &vec[vec.capacity())`* to be used as a normal array" isn't true. The allowable range is *`[&vec[0], &vec[vec.size())`*.

Comment: There is no way to avoid the unnecessary initialization that the first resize() causes?

Comment: +1 Of course this has the problem of unneccessarily initializing the chars before overwriting them, but in C++ it won't get any better.

Comment: 99% certainty the extra initialization will be dwarfed by the cost of your I/O anyway.

Comment: Then I'd rather just use the temporary buffer + insert. It should be at least as efficient, and I don't have to worry about reallocation too often (or does resize() take the same steps to minimize the number of reallocations?)

Comment: @user984228: The question is whether that is a problem. If you have measured and that initialization becomes a bottleneck (I would not expect that) then you might need to consider implementing your own data structure... Note: *if and only if*, I am not trying to have you implement your own data type, but rather realize that in most cases that will not be a performance bottleneck --i.e. wherever you are reading from is probably much slower than the cost of that initialization.

Comment: @user984228: As of reallocations, if you `resize` to a given size, that will trigger a single allocation to a capacity at least as big as the size you requested.

Comment: Btw, I used file I/O as an example, but the question was general. The external data could come from anywhere, possibly not much more expensive to generate than a simple memset(buf, 0, N).

Comment: @user984228 If it's already in a buffer that you could memcpy from then you could *also* use the vector `reserve` and `insert` combination.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: It seems that insert() grows the vector in an intelligent way (not *just* enough to hold the inserted data), so it seems much simpler to keep doing what I have been doing. Thanks for all the answers, at least I know that there is no better way to do this with vectors.

Comment: @user984228: I don't know what you meant by *intelligent, not just enough to hold the inserted data*. My feeling is that you have a preconception that might or not be correct and are making conclusions based on that. What is the *intelligent* bit that `insert` does and will help you here?

Comment: @user984228 If you really fear the initialization (which could be a problem with more complex objects, but surely not with chars), you can also use `std::get_temporary_buffer` instead of a `std::vector`, perhaps together with `std::uninitialized_copy` or a more general `std::raw_storage_iterator`, but then you have the disadvantage of working with plain arrays, instead of a `std::vector`.

Comment: @MarkB: would not you expect a good implementation of insert (range) to be specialized with a single reserve call for random iterators ?

Comment: @user984228: `Then I'd rather just use the temporary buffer + insert. It should be at least as efficient,`  Incorrect.  The temporary buffer avoids the zero initialization, reads into buffer, then requires a copy from buffer to vector.  Vector resize has a zero initialization, then reads into vectors.  Zero initialization is _at least_ as fast, probably faster, than a copy.  Ergo, resize is still faster than a buffer.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: What I mean is that, if make a program that reads a file into a vector in 4 kB blocks, it is *really* fast if you use insert(). I assume that every time it needs to reallocate, it doubles the memory (or something like that), so that the next allocation won't happen immediately after. When I put a vec.reserve(4096) before every insert, it runs insanely slow (I'm talking milliseconds vs minutes). With insert(), I can just append the data I need without worrying about reallocation, because it doesn't happen on every insert (unlike reserve).

Comment: I meant to say: "vec.reserve(vec.capacity() + 4096)", not just "vec.reserve(4096)" (but I'm sure everyone knew that ;)).

Comment: @user984228: of course it does, the correct code is `vec.reserve(vec.size()+4096)`. If you use `size` you benefit from exponentional growth. With `capacity` you systematically grow the buffer, and end up with a much higher capacity that you will ever use.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: No, on my implementation, reserve() gives you exactly what you asked for. If you do vector::reserve(N) where N > capacity() it reallocates to N.

Comment: @Matthieu M. It would be somewhat expected but the standard doesn't require it and g++ 4.2 anyway doesn't (directly) differentiate between forward and random access iterators in its input range. What it does however is use `std::distance` to preallocate for *any* iterator type.

Comment: @user984228 of course using a linearly increasing size for your reserve is going to cause significant performance problems as it continually has to copy your data around every time you increase it. If you use `resize` though it will use its normal size-scaling algorithm rather than linearly increasing it.

Comment: @user984228: crap, that's pretty short-sighted... well, then just implement exponential growth yourself :x

Comment: @Matthieu M. But if he properly used `resize` instead of `reserve` he'd get the scaling growth factor automatically.

Answer (score 14):

Another, newer, question, a duplicate of this one, has [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15220853/673852), which looks like exactly what is asked here. Here's its copy (of v3) for quick reference:

> It is a known issue that initialization can not be turned off even
>   explicitly for `std::vector`.
>
> People normally implement their own `pod_vector<>` that does not do
>   any initialization of the elements.
>
> Another way is to create a type which is layout-compatible with char,
>   whose constructor does nothing:
>
> ```
> struct NoInitChar
> {
>     char value;
>     NoInitChar() {
>         // do nothing
>         static_assert(sizeof *this == sizeof value, "invalid size");
>         static_assert(__alignof *this == __alignof value, "invalid alignment");
>     }
> };
>
> int main() {
>     std::vector<NoInitChar> v;
>     v.resize(10); // calls NoInitChar() which does not initialize
>
>     // Look ma, no reinterpret_cast<>!
>     char* beg = &v.front().value;
>     char* end = beg + v.size();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 9):

It looks like you can do what you want in C++11 (though I haven't tried this myself). You'll have to define a custom allocator for the vector, then use `emplace_back()`.

First, define

```
struct do_not_initialize_tag {};
```

Then define your allocator with this member function:

```
class my_allocator {
    void construct(char* c, do_not_initialize_tag) const {
        // do nothing
    }

    // details omitted
    // ...
}
```

Now you can add elements to your array without initializing them:

```
std::vector<char, my_allocator> buf;
buf.reserve(N);
for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i)
    buf.emplace_back(do_not_initialize_tag());
int M = read(fd, buf.data(), N);
buf.resize(M);
```

The efficiency of this depends on the compiler's optimizer. For instance, the loop may increment the size member variable N times.

Comment: You cannot 'emplace_back' anything other than 'char's to your 'std::vector' of chars

Answer (score 2):

Your program fragment has entered the realm of undefined behavior.

when `buf.empty()` is true, `buf[0]` has undefined behavior, and therefore `&buf[0]` is also undefined.

This fragment probably does what you want.

```
vector<char> buf;
buf.resize(N); // preallocate space
int M = read(fd, &buf[0], N);
buf.resize(M); // disallow access to the remainder
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing into and after the `size()`th element is an undefined behavior.

Next example copies whole file into a vector in a c++ way (no need to know the file's size and no need to preallocate the memory in the vector):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    typedef std::istream_iterator<char> istream_iterator;
    std::ifstream file("example.txt");
    std::vector<char> input;

    file >> std::noskipws;
    std::copy( istream_iterator(file), 
               istream_iterator(),
               std::back_inserter(input));
}
```

Comment: of course you can also call `reserve` beforehand with the file size to avoid all the reallocations.