# vector vs dynamic array benchmarks - what is the bottleneck?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, benchmarking

It's encouraged to use STL over dynamic arrays but I'm curious what could be the bottleneck? `MAX_PACKET_LENGTH` is `32768`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark                                    Time           CPU Iterations
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BM_VectorInit                             1335 ns       1193 ns     497778
BM_RawInit                                  58 ns         55 ns   10000000


static void BM_VectorInit(benchmark::State &state)
{
    for (auto _ : state) 
    {
        std::vector<char> a(MAX_PACKET_LENGTH);
    }
}

static void BM_RawInit(benchmark::State &state)
{
    for (auto _ : state) 
    {
        auto a = new char[MAX_PACKET_LENGTH];
        delete[] a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure but a reasonable optimizer would remove both pieces of code.

Comment: "*It's encouraged to use STL over dynamic arrays*" yes, this is for you the programmer and anyone else who ever has to look at your code. The price you pay for this is a little overhead.

Comment: What about `auto a = new char[MAX_PACKET_LENGTH]{};`? `vector` will zero initialize the array.

Comment: Also, the equivalent raw array version would be `auto a = new char[MAX_PACKET_LENGTH]{};`

Comment: As @juan says, you need to actually do something with the vector/array to prevent the compiler from optimising the code away - I have a short blog article on the topic at https://latedev.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/the-joy-of-benchmarks/

Comment: [Take a look](https://godbolt.org/g/WAWTti).  `<no assembly generated>` means that with optimizations enabled, those functions do nothing at all.  Benchmarking can be a tricky art.

Comment: Here is the [assembly generated](https://godbolt.org/g/1AZJDx) for each version-ish

Comment: If you ever write a naked `delete` without a *very good reason*, your code will fail my code review!

Comment: What compiler, what optimization options, and what hardware, and what OS?  This is not a [mcve].  `clang -O3` with `-stdlib=libc++` can often optimize away creation of a `std::vector`, but not with `libstdc++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as @juanchopanza suggests - we can't reproduce your figures if you don't provide a proper test program; you've just given us two functions which do nothing and won't result in anything in the binary.

Anyway, it seems the overhead is due to `std::vector` zero-initializing the `char` values.

If you want to avoid that happening, or just to level the playing field for benchmarking, use [a struct which wraps a char and doesn't initialize it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38151722/1593077) as the vector element type, and run your tests again. I wouldn't recommend actually using such a silly struct in production code though - use the types you actually need.

And speaking of using what you need - it's perfectly ok to use:

```
auto buffer_ptr = std::make_unique<char[]>(MAX_PACKET_LENGTH);
```

and then maybe:

```
auto buffer = std::span<char>(raw_buffer.get(), MAX_PACKET_LENGTH);
```

and you can use [spans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723819/what-is-a-span-and-when-should-i-use-one) almost everywhere you can use `std::vector`s. (Note, though, that `std::span` is only coming in C++20 and for now you'll need a GSL implementation).

Comment: It could be noted that `std::vector<char> a; a.reserve(MAX_PACKET_LENGTH);` would be a closer match in behavior.

Comment: @DrewDormann: Well, yes, but that means OP would need to resize the vector later on.

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing the cost of constructing a `std::vector` with the cost of allocating an array on the heap.  When you create a `std::vector`, it internally allocates an array on the heap, but there is additional overhead since the `std::vector` is itself an object that needs to be constructed and stored (possibly on the stack or on the heap).  Therefore, it should take longer to create a `std::vector` than it takes to create a `new char[]`.

That being said, there is another difference between `BM_RawInit` and `BM_VectorInit`.  When you construct a `std::vector` with one integer argument, as in `std::vector<char> a(MAX_PACKET_LENGTH)`, two things happen.  Space will be allocated on the heap for `MAX_PACKET_LENGTH` items *and* those items will also be default constructed.  On the other hand, when you do `new char[MAX_PACKET_LENGTH]`, only allocation occurs.

For a better comparison, try to create a third benchmark that only allocates space, like this:

```
static void BM_VectorReserve(benchmark::State &state)
{
    for (auto _ : state) 
    {
        std::vector<char> a;
        a.reserve(MAX_PACKET_LENGTH);
    }
}
```

This isn't a perfect comparison, though, because a small amount of memory will be allocated on the first line where we declare `a`, and then when we call `reserve`, that initial memory will be released.  After that, the `std::vector` will allocate enough space for `MAX_PACKET_LENGTH` items.  In real code, this is often negligible, but for the sake of your benchmark, it would partially explain why `BM_VectorReserve` takes longer than `BM_RawInit`.

Comment: No, a vector is really not at all a wrapper around arrays.

Comment: VectorInit 1426ns, VectorReserve 229ns

Comment: @DamianKalinowski Cool, so you're seeing that VectorReserve is much closer to RawInit, but you still pay some penalty for using the STL container, rather than the raw array

Comment: Any reason for the down votes?  As the OP just showed, I provided useful feedback

Comment: @einpoklum How would you implement a vector without dynamic arrays (or malloc)?

Comment: @TimJohns: 1. There isn't really such a thing as "dynamic arrays" in C++. Arrays are not dynamic. The fact that arrays decay to pointers doesn't mean pointers are arrays. 2. Arrays exist on the stack. 3. `std::vector` uses new, not `malloc()`, although granted - behind the scenes it could well be `malloc()`.

Comment: @einpoklum Sorry, I used the wrong term.  I meant to say "dynamically allocated array", rather than "dynamic array".  I will update the post to make that clear.  And actually, `std::vector` is itself a "dynamic array", according to the Wikipedia definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Comment: @TimJohns: Ok, you can think of an `std::vector` as a "dynamic array". But C and C++ arrays, as such, are never dynamic in that way. Remember that the type of `new int[whatever]`, is `int *`, not `int[100]`.

Comment: @einpoklum Just updated the post.  Hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: @TimJohns: Still not quite there. You can't allocate arrays on the heap. Arrays live on the stack (unless they're inside another structure that gets allocated on the heap), and their size is always fixed. Also, the space for the actual `std::vector` may well be optimized away, and if it isn't it's still inconsequential compared to the initialization of the elements.

Comment: @einpoklum: I think you're being overly pedantic.  It's totally normal to talk about using `malloc` to allocate an array, or to say that a function accepts an array when the args are really pointer,length and you don't care where the array lives.  (At least that's the case in C, where you don't have the option of wrapping it up in an STL container).  And BTW, arrays can live in static storage, too, not automatic storage.  If you're going to be super-pedantic about C++ terminology, don't assume there's a stack or a heap.

Comment: @einpoklum You and I have a fundamental difference of opinion here.  You're saying that `char a[5]` is an array, but that `char* b = new char[5]` is not an array.

Comment: C++ calls `new type[99]` an array new expression, so using the term array is appropriate here. Think of it as creating an array on the free store and returning a pointer to the start of it.